# Book about a man who can freeze time

Tags: story-identification, books

I only read the book(s) maybe a couple of years ago. It is about a man who can kind of freeze time in our modern world and step into the frozen area and do stuff but then when he comes out of the frozen time everything he did in the frozen world was not seen. For example, he was chasing someone but lost them in a crowd and he stepped into the frozen world and can spend as much time tracking the person he was chasing by walking all possible routes, when he left this frozen place no time in the real world had passed. Not sure how many books in the series. I thought it was a Brandon Sanderson book but it does not seem to be.

Comment: This is a fairly common trope, and I think we'll need more information to be able to find the right book. I've [read](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/953082.Whizzard_) at [least](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3517540-bernards-watch) two books myself based on this idea. Please check [our guidelines on asking good story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31394). In particular, you can try to remember details like: how old was this book when you read it? what country was it set in? anything about the plot beyond this man's ability? how did he get this power?

Comment: I don't remember much more than what I wrote. My memory is terrible. I suppose it was set in the USA during this age. The main character did not have any kind of device that gave him this ability and I believe there were others who could do the same thing. He could learn to fight in the frozen place and beat people up but when he left the frozen time those people where not touched.

Comment: There is a movie called "Next" with Nicolas Cage based on the Novel "The Golden Man" from  Philip K. Dick. They can not freeze time but they see their future. I remember a scene where Cage searches a bomb by taking at each crossing in the room virtaully both ways (splitting into two Nicolas Cages). He does not realy go all that ways but just decided to go there, see into the future what comes out and then decide to go the other way, see into the future what lies there and then decide to go a different way and so forth. Until he has tried all routes in a short time.

Comment: Good movie but not even close. Maybe the guy did not actually freeze time in the sense that everything froze in the whole world. He could step into his own reality I guess and everything was like the real world, he could interact with anything such as smashing something or pushing over a human but it had not effect in the real world. Then he could come out of it and not time would have passed in the real world.

Comment: Good job! That is the one. I read the first book. I thought he called it the quiet but when I searched that I got hits for the movie the quiet place. Thanks

Comment: @AdrianWalker assuming you were talking about Jim's answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left. Please do - it will show everyone the mystery was solved and reward both Jim and you with some reputation :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [Mind Dimensions](https://www.goodreads.com/series/141102-mind-dimensions) by Dima Zales. The first book is called "The Thought Readers".

> You see, I have a unique ability. I can go outside time into my own personal version of reality—the place I call “the Quiet”—where I can explore my surroundings while the rest of the world stands still.

Answer (score 1):

It could part of the [Pathfinder](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8100267-pathfinder?from_search=true) series by Orson Scott Card. Most of the characters have time related abilities and do use them to track individuals.

Comment: Could you [edit] to explain why you think this is correct? It might be helpful to take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9444/58193).

Comment: If I recall, Pathfinder has the characters able to see the paths of people through time, not pause time itself. It has been a few years since I've read it though.

Answer (score 1):

The description immediately reminded me of **The Girl, the Gold Watch, and Everything,**  by John D. MacDonald (1962).     The gimmick time-stopping gizmo is left to a youngster when an eccentric uncle expires...

I'm not recalling sequels by the author, but there were motion picture
adaptations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure it's by Brandon Sanderson, it could be Snapshot, but that's a bit of a stretch. It's about detectives using a reconstruction of events to find evidence of crimes.

Edit: I haven't read the book, and my comment is based on a summary and the first chapter. Specific elements I can point to include the lack of impact on the world (since he's in a reconstruction), and the opportunity to pursue many leads (because the situation can be run several times). However, the similarities seem to be coincidental.

Comment: Hi there. Could you [edit] in the elements that make you think this could be the one, such as quotes etc, which match what the asker remembered? Even if not everything match, and there's already an accepted answer, it could be useful to future readers :)